# window.localStorage.setItem not executing in onkeydown callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to implement an `onkeydown` event handler into my `react` app to close the settings screen by pressing `ESC`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress, false);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress, false);
    };
  }, [])

  const saveSettings = () => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("storage.ls.version", CURRENT_LOCALSTORAGE_SCHEMA_VERSION);

    window.localStorage.setItem("auth.token", authInput);
    window.localStorage.setItem("filter.class", classInput);
    window.localStorage.setItem(
      "filter.subjects",
      JSON.stringify(subjectsInput.filter((v: string) => v.trim() !== ""))
    );

    props.dismiss();
  };

  const handleKeyPress = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (event.key === "Escape") {
      saveSettings();
    }
  };
```

The callback does execute, `props.dismiss()` (in `saveSettings`) runs just fine. But the changes don't seem to be saved to `localStorage`. However, when I use the same `saveSettings` function on a press of a button (which I have been doing already before), it works and saves as expected.

I wasn't able to find something, but is there a restriction that prevents usage of localStorage in event callbacks? Or is there another reason it doesn't work as expected?

---

See the comment thread under the question; here's the code that reads the localStorage:

```
const [authInput, setAuthInput] = useState(window.localStorage.getItem("auth.token") ?? "");

const [classInput, setClassInput] = useState(window.localStorage.getItem("filter.class") ?? "");
const [subjectsInput, setSubjectsInput] = useState(
  JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("filter.subjects") ?? "[]")
);
```

Comment: Can you show the values of `authInput` and `classInput` ? Are they actually primitive values? . And where do you read out the values again? Maybe the localStorage props are not correctly accessed?

Comment: Yes, I can display `authInput` and `classInput` - they are state for controlled inputs. They are both `string`s. As I wrote, when `saveSettings()` is ran via button press, everything saves fine.

Comment: Okay. Can you share the code in which you access the localstorage to get the values again?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the question, although I am not sure where this is going to be honest, as I have already mentioned everything works fine if I use the button instead of the `onkeydown` listener.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues here that are contributing to your issue:

1. The `handleKeyPress` function is bound as the event handler for the `keydown` event in the first `useEffect`, and so it holds the context at that point in time when it runs. So say you have values in local storage already like `authInput = apple`, `classInput = english` and `subjectsInput = ''`, and you change the value to `authInput = banana`, then you hit `ESC`, the value that will be stored in `authInput` will be `apple` again because that was the initial value of `authInput` when you attached `handleKeyPress` to the `keydown` event in the DOM, and will always be `apple`! So it 'looks' as if the value isn't changing no matter what you do. To fix this, you need to add `handleKeyPress` as a dependency of that first `useEffect()`. This function context changes with every state change, because the `saveSettings()` function has different values for `authInput`, `classInput` and all the other values it's referencing, whenever the state changes. So the first change you need to make is the following:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress, false);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress, false);
    };
  }, [handleKeyPress]); // add the function as a dependency
```

2. `handleKeyPress` doesn't need to change if the values / functions it's referencing inside doesn't change. So use React's `useCallback()` to specify this relationship:

```js
  const handleKeyPress = useCallback((event) => {
    if (event.key === "Escape") {
      saveSettings();
    }
  }, [saveSettings]);
```

See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback for more on this.

3. Lastly, apply the same treatment to `saveSettings()` because that function depends on three values:

```js
  const saveSettings = useCallback(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("storage.ls.version", CURRENT_LOCALSTORAGE_SCHEMA_VERSION);

    window.localStorage.setItem("auth.token", authInput);
    window.localStorage.setItem("filter.class", classInput);
    window.localStorage.setItem(
      "filter.subjects",
      JSON.stringify(subjectsInput.filter((v: string) => v.trim() !== ""))
    );

    props.dismiss();
  }, [authInput, classInput, subjectsInput]);
```

Whenever the state of `authInput`, `classInput` or `subjectsInput` changes, React will run the cleanup that you specified in the `useEffect()` and re-run the effect with the new handler that has the correct state values in its run-time context.

If you still don't understand why this is happening, that's ok! Don't fret - I highly encourage you to read how Closures work in Javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures or https://javascript.info/closure

Lastly, I want to mention some code smells for you that you might want to cleanup:

1. When setting the initial states for all of your state variables, wrap the expensive operation of reading from `localStorage` in a function so React only runs it once, instead of every re-render.

```js
const [authInput, setAuthInput] = useState(window.localStorage.getItem("auth.token") ?? "");

// instead do this
const [authInput, setAuthInput] = useState(() => window.localStorage.getItem("auth.token") ?? "");
```

2. Is `subjectsInput` guaranteed to be an array when you run `filter()` on it in `saveSettings()`? You might want to account for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have a react hook that might help you.

useKeyboardEvents.ts

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

export type UseKeyboardEventsProps = {
    [key in keyof WindowEventMap]?: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject;
};

export const useKeyboardEvents = (value: UseKeyboardEventsProps) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        Object.entries(value).forEach((item) => {
            const [key, funct] = item;
            window.addEventListener(
                key,
                funct as EventListenerOrEventListenerObject,
                false
            );
        });

        return () => {
            Object.entries(value).forEach((item) => {
                const [key, funct] = item;
                window.removeEventListener(
                    key,
                    funct as EventListenerOrEventListenerObject,
                    false
                );
            });
        };
    }, [value]);
};
```

Use it like follows.  Note: I used keydown like in your code, but I think it would be better to listen to keyup. (replace your useEffect with the following)

```
  useKeyboardEvents({
    keydown: (event: any) => {
      if (event.key === 'Escape') {
        saveSettings();  
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: I know it's very similar to what you are already doing, but it handles removing the event handlers as well, so you don't get clashes.

Comment: The OP is removing the event handler also. The only difference is that this uses an anonymous arrow function rather than a named arrow function. What's not clear is why it's not working in the OP's case, the answer to which would be better than trying to sell your hook.

Comment: Not selling anything, my solution works. 100% works, I have tested it extensively before I posted.  However you are right, he is removing the event handler, somehow my brain didn't notice that.  My guess would be that the useEffect is creating a new function every render.  It could also possibly  be solved by wrapping saveSetting in a useCallback and passing that in the dependency array.